# How to set few types on google.maps.places.autocomplete?

Tags: google-maps

I want to show cities and coutries, but I get just cities

This works

```
    var options = {
      types: ['(cities)'],
    };

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

This doesn't works

```
    types: ['(cities)','(coutry)'],

    types: ['(cities),(coutry)'],

    types: ['(cities,coutry)'],
```

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never this does work I think

```
types: ['(cities,country)']
```